# gem5 two levels of cache hierarchy in SE mode (x86 ISA)

Tags: performance, caching, memory, x86, gem5

#### Problem description

I am trying to evaluate the performance by changing the size of the caches using gem5 simulator (x86 ISA in SE mode).
I used the example configuration script ([gem5/configs/example/se.py](https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/stable/configs/example/se.py), which uses the script [gem5/configs/common/CacheConfig.py](https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/stable/configs/common/CacheConfig.py) for the configuration of cache memories).

I noticed that:

- Using caches ("--caches" option), performance increase. It sounds good!
- Using caches and enable also L2 cache level ("--caches", "--l2cache" options) performance does not increase.

I tried 2 configurations for the caches, and I obtain the following results:

1. L1D=32kB, L2=256kB

   ```
   simSeconds                                   0.063785
   system.cpu.dcache.overallMisses::total         196608
   system.cpu.dcache.overallHits::total         13434883
   system.l2.overallMisses::total                 196610
   system.l2.overallHits::total                       45
   ```
2. L1D=32kB, L2=512kB

   ```
   simSeconds                                   0.063785
   system.cpu.dcache.overallMisses::total         196608
   system.cpu.dcache.overallHits::total         13434883
   system.l2.overallMisses::total                 196610
   system.l2.overallHits::total                       45
   ```

Statistics are exactly the same for bot configurations, as the L2 size is not considered.
Moreover, of all the misses in L1, only 45 correspond to hits in L2. I don't think it's normal behaviour.

Any suggestion on how to fix this problem? Maybe it is some *port connection* that I need to implement in configuration file.

#### Benchmark

I tested cache configurations with a simple "vector addition" example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define LKMC_M5OPS_DUMPSTATS  __asm__ __volatile__ (".word 0x040F; .word 0x0041;" : : "D" (0), "S" (0) :)
#define LKMC_M5OPS_RESETSTATS __asm__ __volatile__ (".word 0x040F; .word 0x0040;" : : "D" (0), "S" (0) :)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int N = 1024 * 1024 * 1;

    float* A = new float[N];
    float* B = new float[N];
    float* C = new float[N];

    LKMC_M5OPS_RESETSTATS;
    for(auto i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    }
    LKMC_M5OPS_DUMPSTATS;

    delete[] A;
    delete[] B;
    delete[] C;

    return 0;
}
```

#### gem5 command

For completeness I write the command I used for the simulation:

```
build/X86/gem5.opt  ./configs/example/se.py --cmd=./tests/test-progs/add_vector/add_vector --cpu-type=TimingSimpleCPU --caches --l2cache --l1d_size=32kB --l1i_size=32kB --l2_size=[256,512]kB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those results look normal for this microbenchmark.

Your arrays are much bigger than L2 cache, and you only traverse them once.  Loads or stores either hit in L1d (in a line that's already been accessed) or miss all the way to DRAM the first time a cache line is touched.  You only make one pass over the arrays, so there's zero reuse.

Unless you're simulating an L2 with a hardware prefetcher, there's no way L2 can have a line ready when you haven't touched it yet.  Even then, with SIMD vectorization this probably runs faster than HW prefetch could keep up with.  L2 hits might happen on a rare conflict miss in L1d.

If you want to see L2 matter, maybe put a repeat loop around the array-sum inner loop, and use arrays larger than L1d but small enough for all 3 to fit in L2.  Or anything else with some locality over a larger time/space scale than L1d can handle.

Your current test only has spatial locality within one single cache line, never coming back to them later.  So at most you have 3 to 6 cache lines needing to be hot at any one time to achieve the best case of hits for accesses to later floats in the same line.